# copyTo gives error code 1

Tags: ios, cordova

I am having trouble finding the error im making. Im getting the right entries and paths through out my code, i think, but still it goes into the movingError in the addFileToDirectory function.

Here is the code im having trouble with:

```
function addToFileSystem(entry){
  window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(entry, onPhotoURISuccess, movingError);
}

function onPhotoURISuccess(entry){
  console.log('1.1');
  fileEntry = entry
  window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, createOrSelectDirectory, movingError);
  console.log('1.2');
}

function createOrSelectDirectory(fileSys){
  console.log('2.1');
  var myFolderName = 'photos';
  fileSys.root.getDirectory(myFolderName, {create:true}, addFileToDirectory, movingError);
  console.log('2.2');
}

function addFileToDirectory(directory){
  console.log('3.1');
  var date = new Date();
  var fileName = date.getTime();
  var newFileName = fileName + '.jpg';
  console.log('newFileName:' + newFileName + ', directory: ' + directory.toURL() + ', fileEntry: ' + fileEntry.toURL());
  fileEntry.copyTo(directory, newFileName, OnMoveSuccess, movingError);
  console.log('3.2');
}

function OnMoveSuccess(fileEntry){
  console.log(fileEntry.toURL() + ' moved successfully');
}

function movingError(error) {
  console.log('error occoured while moving file with error code: ' + error.code);
}
```

Output in the console:

```
2014-04-03 09:33:29.678 HelloWorld[274:60b] 1.1
2014-04-03 09:33:29.683 HelloWorld[274:60b] 1.2
2014-04-03 09:33:29.685 HelloWorld[274:60b] 2.1
2014-04-03 09:33:29.693 HelloWorld[274:60b] 2.2
2014-04-03 09:33:29.694 HelloWorld[274:60b] 3.1
2014-04-03 09:33:29.695 HelloWorld[274:60b] newFileName:1396510409691.jpg, directory: cdvfile://localhost/persistent/photos/, fileEntry: cdvfile://localhost/temporary/cdv_photo_014.jpg
2014-04-03 09:33:29.699 HelloWorld[274:60b] 3.2
2014-04-03 09:33:29.700 HelloWorld[274:60b] error occoured while moving file with error code: 1
```

I did try to remove some of the movingError to check where it was called, and its from the fileEntry.copyTo.

I have the file plugin installed aswell.

This is for IOS btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote your code a bit. Before we start though, not that you want the Camera to use the NATIVE_URI, not FILE_URI:

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onCamSuccess, onCamFail, 
{quality:50, 
sourceType:Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
destinationType:Camera.DestinationType.NATIVE_URI});
```

Ok, so before going further, note that I'm not happy with this code, because every time you take a picture, it is going to get a hook to the file system and then the folder you want. This should be done *once*, not every time.

```
function onCamSuccess(imgdata) {
    console.log(imgdata);
    $("#entryPicture").val(imgdata);
    $("#imgPreview").attr("src", imgdata);
    //copy the image to global scope
    imageUri = imgdata;
    window.requestFileSystem(window.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, onError);
}
```

Now let's see gotFS

```
function gotFS(fs){
    var myFolderName = 'photos';
    //copy file system to global scope
    fileSys = fs;
    fileSys.root.getDirectory(myFolderName, {create:true}, addFileToDirectory, onError);
}
```

Then let's look at addFileToDirectory

```
function addFileToDirectory(directory){
    var date = new Date();
    var fileName = date.getTime();
    var newFileName = fileName + '.jpg';

    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(imageUri, function(fe) {
        fe.copyTo(directory, newFileName, function(e) {
            console.log('in theory, done');
        }, onError);
    },onError);
}
```

And there ya go. This worked for me. As I said, it could be done nicer I think.

Comment: navigator.camera.getPicture(onCamSuccess, onCamFail, {quality:50,    sourceType:Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
destinationType:Camera.DestinationType.NATIVE_URI});});                 This doesnt seem to work for me. I'm taking a picture with the camera and then saving the temp file to a persistant place, but first thing is that NATIVE_URI simply returns nothing, other thing is that i use the camera to forward the picture taken. Maybe that isnt the way to do it?

Comment: Are you using the latest version? NATIVE_URI isn't new per se, but, just to be sure. Also, here is a link to my complete file. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/88185/index.js

Comment: I am pretty sure im using newest version. Also a thing i might not have been clear about is that im using an ipad with this app and when i wanna grab the file URI (NATIVE_URI/FILE_URI) i wanna do it when i take a picture. When i try to use your code it opens a menu, where i can choose a picture from the camera roll, where the picture aren't present and shouldn't be.

Comment: So to your last sense - the SOURCE value can be tweaked and isn't relevant to this discussion (I believe!) so it isn't a big deal if you set it back. But why do you say you want to use the FILE_URI? Why not use the NATIUVE_URI?

Comment: That's what i thought aswell, regarding the source. I really wanna use NATIVE_URI, but when i use it, its empty. That's why i so far only got data from the FILE_URI. As soon as i change FILE_URI -> NATIVE_URI, the fail function is called instead of success. Everything else seem to work, but when i change that single value, nothing works anymore.

Comment: Weird. Um - not sure what to say. I can give you a zip of my entire project if you want?